# CakePHP containable behaviour not firing

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, containable

First time using Cake and its containable behaviour, but it's not working as expected ... or at all.

I'm trying to obtain a list of accessories for a product. Product model HABTM products (alias 'ProductRelation'). Join table is products_products which has two product ids - product_id and related_id. It's against this I want to pull the list of accessories (products driven from the related_id column) for a given product_id

In my Product model, I've added $actsAs = array('Containable');

And in my controller, a quick test of containable using reference from the cookbook fails to contain products at all, even without conditions.

```
debug($this->Product->find('all', array('contain' => 'ProductRelation')));
```

.. returns an array of every product in the db, with ALL related models - images, content tabs, ratings, reviews, pricing, etc I haven't tried applying any 'conditions' against this because the call as written should limit data to the product and it's ProductRelation data, according to the cookbook ...

Any tips?

Comment: I have never used the habtm alias tables but shouldn't your contain consist of an array of models? `'contain' => array('ProductRelation')`

Comment: Do you have this in your AppModel: `var $actsAs = array( 'Containable' );`

Comment: @BarryChapman He says he does.

Comment: 'contain' does not need to be an array, It is cast as an array here https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Model/Behavior/ContainableBehavior.php#L106

Comment: @TimJoyce - let me refer to what he said: `In my Product model, I've added $actsAs = array('Containable');` He has it on `Product` model. I stated to add it in the AppModel - since `Containable` needs to be active on the model being contained, and not simply the one doing the containing. Adding it to `AppModel` will naturally make it available to all models inheriting `AppModel`.

Comment: The model he is trying to contain is `ProductRelation`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you have recursive on. Try using the following:

```
debug($this->Product->find('all', array(
    'contain' => 'ProductRelation',
    'recursive' => -1
)));
```

If that works for you, you should start adding `containable` to the `AppModel` class and setting the `recursive` property to `-1`. This will ensure you only ever get the results you request.

**NB**: Cake does not `join` for HABTM, so you can not use `ProductRelation` in any conditions.

Comment: " Cake does not join for HABTM, so you can not use ProductRelation in any conditions." . dead on, thanks. I worked around it with Joins and running conditions on these. I suppose this seems to be right from other posts.